# What is the behavior on reinstalling an apk?

Tags: android, google-play

When you install an app through the play store / apple store, the online store ends up keeping you updated.

Ex: If you have version v1 and are released to v2 the store itself notifies you and gives the option to upgrade.

What exactly happens in this update? the full apk is downloaded again or is something of the incremental / differential type (downloading only the files that have been updated).

And when you install the off-site apk (without subscription) ... be it debug or relase ... how do updates occur?

Ex:I generated the apk in android studio ( "Generate Signed Bundle" or got it from debug), I transferred it to android and installed it ... if I update the apk and do the procedure again .... I will get two different versions of the same apk or does it overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the APKs comes with certain certificate signature, if it matches then only update will occur, else you need to uninstall the existing one.

The size of the update depends on how you published the update. If you upload APK then the full-size download will happen. If you upload app bundle then only the diff size will download.

While update it keeps the application data and the database records if the developer has written proper DB migration logic.

For eg. in version 1, the user table has 5 fields and in version 2 you have added 2 more fields to it. Then you need to write the migration logic (Alter table query) so that the version 1 user data properly map to version 2 user table.
Refer [this post](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-sqlite-database-migration-b9ad47811d34)  for more details.

Debug APK and release APK will have a different signature, you can't update the release app with a debug build and vice versa.

Comment: "if the developer has written proper DB migration logic" Could you detail this part a little?

Comment: Added details, please check